# R language: loop for each column in dataframe to get datatype

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm beginner in **R** language.

I'm going to calculate One-Sample-T-Test for all numeric column in a dataframe.

My code is

```
for (col_name in names(iris))
{
    col_vector_class <- class(iris[col_name])
    if (col_vector_class == "numberic")
    {
      t.test_res <- t.test(col_vector, 10)
    }
}
```

The code cannot run into `t.test` line because the `class(iris[col_name])` always returns `data.frame` data type.

Could you please help me to fix my code?

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this would be to do a t-test or return NA (or anything else you want). Result is a list which can be further processed excluding NAs, extracting p-values...

```
sapply(iris, FUN = function(x, groups) {
  if (is.numeric(x)) {
    t.test(x ~ groups)
  } else {
    NA
  }
}, groups = sample(c("a", "b"), nrow(iris), replace = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a comma in the data frame selection

```
col_vector_class <- class(iris[,col_name])
```

This selects all rows and column named col_name. Not specifying the col_name just subsets the data.frame and returns one with just that column. From here you can do your check. However instead of saving the type them comparing to a string you can use the built in function is.numeric() to check if the vector is numeric

```
for (col_name in names(iris))
{
    if (is.numeric(iris[,col_name]))
    {
      t.test_res <- t.test(col_vector, 10)
    }
}
```